# Python gives empty list when change loop range

Tags: python, list, range

hi everyone i have a problem with my codes below. as you can see i am trying to find "near power sum" numbers(35---> 3^2 + 5^2 = 34) when i arrange my range 10 to 100 program gives the exact results 35 and 75. however when i change the range like 100000 to 500000 or 1000000 it gives nothing, just an empty list. could you please help me about this?

```
import math

mylist=[]

for i in range(100000,1000000):
    a =0
    b=0
    num=i

    while num >= 1:
        b = num%10
        a= a+(b**2)
        num = math.trunc(num/10)

    if a == i-1 or a== i+1:
        mylist.append(i)

print(mylist)
```

Comment: Maybe there is no number in between `100000-1000000` that meets your condition?

Comment: As @RustamGarayev mentions, have you checked that there any numbers in the higher range that satisfy your logic?

Answer (score 0):

Numbers from your new range have only 5 digits. The biggest "near power sum" you can get in that range will be 9^2 * 5 = 405 which is less than your lower boundary 1e+5. So your code works properly as there is no way your condition can be satisfied for that range.

Answer (score 0):

Let us take a decimal number with n digits n>2. I will assume that it has no leading 0, so its first digit is >=1.

Then the number is >= 10**(n-1)

Its digits are at most 9 so the sum of the square of its digits is <= n*81

For n =4, the number is >=1000 while the sum of the square of its digits is < 4*81 = 324: no deal...

And it will be worse when n increases.